# The spectrum of a product of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Suppose $A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. In general, we know that there is no relationship between $\sigma(AB)$ and $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$ without assuming that perhaps $A$ and $B$ commute. What I've been wondering about is if we can say anything if $A$ and $B$ have finite spectrum - can we conclude that $AB$ has finite spectrum? Or are there examples of bounded operators $A$ and $B$ with finite spectrum but $\sigma(AB)$ is infinite? If nothing can be said in general for this problem, what if $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint involutions (i.e. $A^* = A$, $B^*=B$ and $A^2 = B^2 = I$)?

I haven't been able to make any serious headway on this due to the complicated nature of a spectrum of a product of operators. I've had a string of if and only ifs for when $AB-\lambda I$ is invertible but nothing enlightening came of it. In the self-adjoint involution case, I would think that the spectral theorem could play a big role but I don't see how to invoke it here in a meaningful way. After some scouring of the internet, I haven't really found any result or even any mention of such a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, the spectrum can be infinite, and pairs of self-adjoint involutions are actually a good class of counterexamples because they can be fully described using the spectral theorem. The irreducible pairs of involutions occur in dimensions $1$ and $2$, and the rest are direct integrals of irreducibles. So every such pair is described by the "spectrum of angles" between them with its spectral measure type (i.e. equivalence class) + multiplicity.

Now, an irreducible pair of involutions in dimension $2$ looks like this:

$A_\alpha = \left[\begin{matrix}1\\
 & -1
\end{matrix}\right], B_\alpha = \left[\begin{matrix}\cos\alpha & \sin\alpha\\
\sin\alpha & -\cos\alpha
\end{matrix}\right]$

The product $A_\alpha B_\alpha$ is the unitary operator that rotates by angle $\alpha$, so its spectrum is $\{e^{i\alpha}, e^{-i\alpha}\}$. Clearly, a direct sum of countably many of these, with different $\alpha$'s, can have infinite spectrum.

Incidentally, we see that every unitary operator whose spectral measure type and multiplicity function are symmetric under complex conjugation is a product of two self-adjoint involutions.

Comment: I have a concern and maybe it's only because it was not explicitly stated but what would you take for $A$ and $B$ in this case? If you are taking a direct sum of countably many with different angles for $B$, shouldn't $B$ also have infinite spectrum?

Comment: No, $B$ itself is an involution, so its spectrum is $\{-1,1\}$. In general the spectrum of a direct sum is the closure of the union of spectra of the summands.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are your involutions; I construct them as $A := \bigoplus_n A_{\alpha_n}$, $B := \bigoplus_n B_{\alpha_n}$

Comment: This is a great answer. I finally got around to working out the details, been pretty bogged down with various kinds of work. It's pretty disappointing that you can't even say much about the product of operators with finite spectra. I wonder if there are additional constraints that can be placed in order to guarantee finiteness in the spectrum of $AB$. That seems like a pretty tall task though.

Comment: I would look for something close to commutativity. Probably nilpotency of the generated Lie algebra should be enough. Or something along these lines...